# Password match verification doesn't work (Express)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, express-validator

I spent some hours trying to figure out what is happening but I couldn't find a way to make it work. I'm using pug, express and express-validator.

First of all, I've defined the inputs in a *form.pug* file:

```
div.form-group
  label(for='password') Password:
  input#password.form-control(type='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' required='true')

div.form-group
  label(for='password_conf') Password confirmation:
  input#password_conf.form-control(type='password' name='password_conf' placeholder='Password confirmation' required='true')
```

Then, I have a file called *userController.js* which basically interacts with the database. As I pointed out earlier, I'm using express-validator to validate the input fields, so naturally I wrote the code below to verify if the field *password* and *password_conf* are identical and if the password's length is greater than 8:

```
    body('password_conf')
    .isLength({ min: 8 }).withMessage('The password must have at least 8 characters.')
    .equals(body('password')).withMessage('The passwords do not match.')
```

It seems to be correct to me, but the error 'The passwords do not match' is always triggered. I verified the POST request and there are no problems with the strings. I've changed **body('password')** for a dummy string and it worked, so I don't really know what is going on here.

I'm really sorry if this a dumb question, I'm new to web development and I don't know much about debugging.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Try to console.log(req.body.password, req.body.password_conf) to see the values

Comment: Can you you share you request body object as well. Thanks